# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Inspiron 14Z

Tags: 12.04, installation

I just got my new Dell Inspiron 14Z laptop, I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04, I already have Windows installed on it.

We can install ubuntu 12.04 but it disappears once we restart it and model is inspiron 5423 ultrabook. I am trying for a dual boot version, i mean to run ubuntu along with Windows.

How do I do it? A quick googling did not help me much.

How do fix it and get it installed.

Comment: What is the error you are facing. Please clarify

Comment: How far have you gotten in this attempt? Black Screen with cursor? Purple Screen? Grub menu? We need details in order to help you fix it.

Comment: Hi thanks for reverting back, we can install ubuntu 12.04 but it disappears once we restart it and model is inspiron 5423 ultrabook. I am trying for a dual boot version, i mean to run ubuntu along with windows

Comment: How did you try to install it? What actually happened when you tried? What do you want to fix? Did you try to install it?

Comment: Please **edit your question** and add specific details for us to better help you. *What* is happening, exactly? At what *point* is it happening? What error *messages* are you encountering?

Comment: I've added info from comments to the question, so it's clear what the problem (probably) is. While the question could still be improved by clarification and the addition of some technical information, I believe it is probably [specifically answerable](http://askubuntu.com/a/168929/22949) in its present form and should not be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> we can install ubuntu 12.04 but it disappears once we restart it and model is inspiron 5423 ultrabook. I am trying for a dual boot version, i mean to run ubuntu along with windows

If you are booting from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD or live USB flash drive and running the installer, and it appears to succeed, but when you remove the installation media and restart you just boot into Windows without an option to select Ubuntu, this *usually* means the GRUB2 boot loader was not properly installed to the Master Boot Record.

The solution to that is to [reinstall GRUB2 to the MBR](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2). You can choose whichever method you prefer. Because they're easiest, I recommend either [using the Boot Repair GUI utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) or using [this method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstall_from_the_LiveCD).

If that doesn't work, then we definitely will need more information to answer your question. Here's the information we need:

- How, exactly, did you install Ubuntu? Provide as much detail as possible.
- In particular, **if you installed Ubuntu inside Windows using Wubi, the above instructions will not help you**, and you'll have to tell us that.
- Boot from the live CD, open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run `sudo parted -l`. Select all the text in the Terminal window, copy it to the clipboard, and edit your question, pasting it into your question and formatting it with the <kbd><$></kbd> tool in the Ask Ubuntu editing toolbar. (You should be able to access the Internet from the live CD system to do this.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The problem was that the boot loader for Ubuntu was in the SSD memory, so I had to go to the setup and choose the SSD (secondary HDD) as the primary boot device.

Answer (score 1):

I was forced to do research project on DELL Inspiron 14z. It install 12.04 okay. But if you looked in dmesg, you would see 2 messages that indicate big problems. One had to with power regulation. The other had to do graphic driver. The messages exhibited in computer shutting off on temperature of CPU. And also random freezes of display in a very unique way because the mouse cursor moved but everything else was frozen. Different kernel versions behave differently on these two problems. My only suggestion is check kernel.log and dmesg and start there if you see any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Download Precise from http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/

Create an Image from ISO in Window(the file you have downloaded)[Burning the cd]

Make sure you set the boot from CD in your bios setup.

Then boot the cd and follow the instruction.

Please make sure you make a swap partition along with root for better performance.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install Ubuntu in Legacy Mode while the Windows running in UEFI mode.
To access Windows again you will have to change
the boot mode to UEFI and when you want to access Ubuntu you've to change to Legacy Mode.

Comment: This sounds more like a workaround.

Comment: Yes, in this new version of Ubuntu (14.04) I got the instalation normally without problems with the UEFI mode.